# Make [openrefine] the canonical tag rather than [google-refine]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I see that there's one vote for making [openrefine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openrefine) a synonym for [google-refine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-refine), and no suggested synonyms for [openrefine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openrefine). I think that's backwards. Besides being the not-obsolete name, [openrefine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openrefine) has more questions, is more active, and has more followers.

So let's make [google-refine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-refine) a synonym of [openrefine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openrefine).